# Stopping Python CSV to JSON to read

Tags: javascript, python, json, csv, data-visualization

i'm working on JS DataVis and use a Python script to convert and filter my CSV data. I'm using `append` and `json.dump`. In the attached img you can see how the script works.

[heres the picture of the python script and the json file it writes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yRV2.jpg)

My problem is, that i want only `trip number 0-6054` to be used. Neither `else: pass` nor `else: break` does work. I also tried using a for loop, but couldn't get it to work at all. 
Right now, the script just doesn't stop and continues to create objects in the JSON file.

I'm all new to Python, sorry if that's a silly question.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please don't post code and data dumps as pictures. It is better to edit your question to include these as text. This makes it easier for us to copy/paste and recreate your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the values in `row` are strings and your code is attempting to do a string comparison. You need to convert the strings to integers first:

```
if int(row['trip number']) < 6054:
    ....
else:
    break
```

Also, if you are using Python 2.x, the file should be opened using `rb`. In Python 3.x, you should add `newline=''` as another parameter.